# Bounding exponential function by n^{-\gamma}

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponentiation, upper-lower-bounds

Assume that we know

$$\exp(-\frac{t^2/2}{np(1-p)+t/3})$$

and our goal is to obtain which value of $t$ we can take such that the above is bounded by $n^{-\gamma}$, for certain constant $\gamma $.

The answer is to take $t=\sqrt{2\gamma np(1-p)\log n}+2\gamma \log n/3$.

But I have idea to obtain it. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Tak logarithms and solve a quadratic in $t$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks!